# Nexus 7 doesn't have sdcard folder when connected to PC

Tags: linux, nexus-7

I've just bought a Nexus 7. When I plugged it into my laptop, it shows the media folder, I'd like to access the sdcard folder just like the other devices. How to transfer files?

I think "adb push" is not a good choice.
[image]

Comment: See also [Better way to connect Galaxy Nexus (ICS) to Linux](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15877/better-way-to-connect-galaxy-nexus-ics-to-linux)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nexus 7 doesn't support UMS (USB Mass Storage) out of box. But, it supports file transfer by MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). MTP allows you to push and pull any type of files from sdcard, but it doesn't allow you to edit files directly on sdcard (like you do with UMS mode).

From your screenshot, it looks like your Nexus 7 is connected with PTP (Photo Transfer Protocol), also known as Camera Mode. Switch to MTP mode and do whatever you want. Also make sure your PC OS supports MTP.

Comment: When I chose MTP, it even didn't show any folder so I chose PTP.

Comment: @Emerald It means that Ubuntu has problem accessing over MTP. Try finding a software for that.

Comment: @Emerald Try using command line.. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/mtp-tools.1.html

Comment: it's not even 'not out of the box' but more 'not at all'

Comment: @ce4 But, few tricks and hacks can enable UMS in Nexus 7. I'd say 'not at all' if there was a limitation from hardware layer.

Comment: Sure, the hardware is not the limitation here. At the moment it's more of a 'not at all' for me. One of the possible ways (just a feature request atm): [UMS support for LuksManager](http://nemesis2.qx.net/forums/index.php/topic,132.0.html) and of course a kernel that supports it.