# Connecting Google Nexus 7 to Linux

Tags: linux, nexus-7

Has someone been able to connect Google Nexus 7 to Linux. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.04?

I've already installed mtp-tools and mtpfs but still cannot get it right. Can someone help?

Comment: Without any special tools, I see the content of /sdcard

Comment: nopes i'm not seeing it

Comment: it clearly says that device loaded as storage but does n't connect

Comment: can you connect any kind of USB flash drives to your Linux computer?

Comment: yes I can, like pendrives ....

Comment: When you connect the device, you should see a "connected as media device" on the nexus screen (I don't know the exact text, I see the german text only "Als Mediengerät abgeschlossen"). On the linux pc, you need tools like libgphoto2 or libmtp. I suggest to install the android sdk, then you can do `adb shell` to look around on the nexus, `adb pull ...` and `adb push ...` to transfer files from/to the sdcard folder. Note, this is different from my earlier comment, I forgot that I used gphotofs.

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27926/nexus-7-doesnt-have-sdcard-folder-when-connected-to-pc

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
mkdir ~/NexusDrive
mtpfs ~/NexusDrive
nautilus ~/NexusDrive
```

Comment: [hortstu](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/27264/hortstu) says:`the above terminal input worked for me with a kindle fire 10.2.6. I just changed NexusDrive to KindleFire`

Comment: Using LinuxMint (Nadia).
I followed the instructions above.
The 'NexusDrive' appears on the desktop.
I can't open it and view contents.
Error message, 'Could not display "/home/paul/NexusDrive". The file is of an unknown type'
If I try to unmount the Nexus 7, 'Unable to unmount NexusDrive. unmount: /home/paul/NexusDrive is not in the fstab (and you are not root)