# How to recognize Nexus 4 as a drive

Tags: nexus-4

I'm looking how to recognize my Nexus 4 as a drive.

Actually it's like a camera.

Any idea?

Comment: We are looking how to help you. Actually, we lack information: Where should it be detected? If on a computer, what OS? What have you tried already? Have you checked [other questions tagged "disk-drive](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disk-drive)? Also, results of this search might prove helpful: http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[storage]+access

Comment: It seems his N4 is in PTP mode, and perhaps he wants to mount it as a Mass Storage Device. I wrote my answer based on those assumptions, but I could be completely missing his real issue. More information in the question would be fantastic.

Comment: Similar: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27926/nexus-7-doesnt-have-sdcard-folder-when-connected-to-pc/27929#27929

Comment: The question is very valid though not unique. He obviously wants USB mass storage back. Doesn't work out of the box. You need root and an app like drivedroid and maybe a modified kernel, e.g. franko kernel for the N4. App is here:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how many modern Android phones (Including all Nexus phones) work. The Nexus 4 can switch between MTP and PTP modes. To overgeneralize a bit, it can use MTP to emulate a Media Device and PTP to emulate a camera.

The Nexus 4 has **no way to mount as a Mass Storage Device** (and thus, no practical way to mount it and get a drive letter for it)

Comment: I need to recover a deleted picture, how can I do it ?

Comment: I'm on windows seven / android 4.3

Comment: @NexusFTW, if you have another question, please make a new question. If this answer was acceptable, please upvote and mark it as accepted.

Comment: He currently doesn't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about that requirement. My mistake.