# Can't USB connect my Motorola Razr to Linux Fedora 16

Tags: usb-connection-mode, motorola-droid-razr

I was trying to connect my Droid Razr to my laptop (Linux Fedora 16) using the USB cable that came with it.  I was hoping that it be mounted on the file system just like a thumb drive but it never came on.  I went to the `/mount` directory but it was empty.  I was able to do it before I upgraded my Droid OS a few months ago but now I can't connect.  I primarly wanted to unload some media files.

How do I connect my Razr to my laptop via USB?

Comment: It's possible that it now uses [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) since you updated it. You might want to take a look at [Better way to connect Galaxy Nexus (ICS) to Linux](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15877/better-way-to-connect-galaxy-nexus-ics-to-linux) to see if the answers prove useful (it's for the GNex, but MTP behavior is not device specific). Does the RAZR have any kind of status bar notification when plugged in? (i.e. "Connected as a media device" or similar)

Comment: Usually, also on Linux, there comes a pop-up asking you what to do with the newly detected storage device (unless you have configured it otherwise). If you decide to open it with something (filemanager, image viewer), it's often mounted in `/media` instead of `/mount` (at least with Ubuntu and derivates), so that might also be woth a look. Aside from that: what Android version are you currently using? At least with 4.1 and up, the *MTP* hint by eldarerathis' comment above is the most likely direction.

Comment: @Izzy -- I don't have that popup now after the upgrade.  I did have it before

Comment: Yepp, and the reason might be you don't have any MTP packages installed. Fedora seems a bit slow on this: I've found packages for all kind of Debian/Ubuntu derivates, but nothing for Fedora. Watch out e.g. for [gMTP](http://gmtp.sourceforge.net/) or mtpfs. If your device is no longer offering UMS, that's the way to go. Of course you might first check the notification area when connected via USB, it might have an USB entry with options for possible connection modes. Maybe the default is "charge only", which also would explain your issue.

Comment: yes, as soon as I plug the device into my laptop, it starts charging the battery.  it doesn't ask me whether i want data or charge.  this MTP package, is this something i need to install on the phone or on the laptop?