# How can I mount my google nexus4 on linuxmint(nadia) computer via usb?

Tags: usb, mount

Also is it any different than ubuntu?

UPDATE:

Using gmtp, I still get the error from the terminal and gmtp crashes when i click on "connect".

The gmtp says the following in the shell:

```
Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee1) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02fe: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02fe: PTP: Protocol error, data expected
```

I'm sure that libtmp teams added nexus4 to their libraries because my nexus4 was being seen by ubuntu-11.04 easily. But my problem is still alive in linuxmint

Comment: If not the same, it's probably very similar, I would imagine. [Better way to connect Galaxy Nexus (ICS) to Linux](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15877/better-way-to-connect-galaxy-nexus-ics-to-linux) might be relevant the underlying issue (MTP) is the same.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39502/16575) where I've explained it for the Kindle Fire and Ubuntu. Don't get confused on the Kindle part, the Linux part is what you need to connect your device via MTP.

Comment: Hey man use this libmtp (link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmtp/)

They say its good and works fine

Answer (score 2):

This question gets asked a lot about Linux in general.  MTP from the default repos will work in Mint, no problem.  I've written [a tutorial on how to get MTP devices recognized under Ubuntu](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-your-mtp-androids-sd-card-on-ubuntu/), but it's the same for Mint:

Install MTP:

1. sudo apt-get install mtpfs

Create a directory to mount your device:

1. sudo mkdir /media/MTPdevice (call the directory whatever you like)
2. sudo chmod 775 /media/MTPdevice
3. sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/MTPdevice

Plug in you phone and use MTP tools to determine the VID and PID (or, if those don't appear in the output, idVendor and idProduct):

1. mtp-detect

Add a rule to udev to handle your phone:

1. gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Text to add:  (substitue VID and PID for "" and "")

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="<vendorId>", ATTR{idProduct}=="<productId>", MODE="0666"
```

Restart udev:

1. sudo service udev restart

You may also need to reboot, depending.

This works on my Linux Mint 15 + MATE box.

**NOTE:**  If you have your device locked (eg, which a swipe code or PIN), you’ll need to unlock it before your SD card(s) can be recognized by MTP and have it mount them for you to access locally.