# Linux doesn't recognize Galaxy S 3

Tags: usb, linux

I've bought a Samsung Galaxy S 3 device today, but found out that I could not get my PC with Fedora 18 (Gnome 3) to recognize it (nothing happens when I plug it in).

As file transfer etc is essential to me, this renders my device pretty much useless (I don't have an SD card slot on my PC at the moment).

Android lets me choose how I connect though: as a "media device (MTP)" or a "camera (PTP)".

Is there a way to simply access the storage on my phone from a Linux machine?

It's pretty ironic because both my PC and my phone are actually running Linux, yet they can't communicate. For a large company like Google/Samsung there's pretty much no excuse for this, as Linux is quite popular nowadays, especially because Google already does most of its work on Linux.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1058:0748 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport 1TB USB 3.0
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

It would seem that the device is somehow recognized.

Comment: Do you have udev rules set up? See this (answer)[http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/fastboot-not-working-on-my-nexus-4/37085#37085] to help you

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15877/better-way-to-connect-galaxy-nexus-ics-to-linux

Comment: Also see [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39502/16575). That would be for MTP. You also might want to have a look at [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/), which is what t0mm13b had in mind when talking about "udev rules". Access via ADB gives you much more power -- while MTP just lets you copy files, basically.